# Coldfusion server is too slow + JVM is taking too much memory coldfusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, jvm, coldfusion-9, fusebox

I have a fuse box application which is working very slow from some days and got stop working after 4-5 hours. I have tried to find the problem and one problem i found that the memory of server is full and found that JVM is taking full ram. I have 8 gb RAM on server.

[image: cpu and memory usage screen shot]

Here is the process detail from task Manager

[image]

Here is my JVM arguments:

```
-server -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home}/../ -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/../lib -Dcoldfusion.sessioncookie.httponly=true -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Dcoldfusion.disablejsafe=true
```

The minimum heap size is 1024 and max heap size is 2048.

Can any one suggest any better settings which would help me to fix it?

Comment: Try to find the job that's causing it and do something about it.

Comment: #Dan Bracuk. thanks for your reply. By job means schedule task of coldfusion?

Comment: By job I mean the .cfm or .cfc file.  It doesn't matter whether or not it's scheduled.

Comment: You may want to try adding some logging to any file/function you think may be the culprit. If you are doing any threading you may want to start there. If you made a recent change and are using version control you may want to revert the changes to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks #Dan and #isMayoAVariable. Yes, i am already finding piece of code which is doing it. But i found nothing, i still think, it is the issue of something else. I have seen that, the database server is also taking full RAM.

Comment: It might be an inpatient user submitting multiple page requests.  That's happened to us.

Comment: #Dan Bracuk. There are some emails sending code which was sending zip with out reason. Which i have removed and made some settings in templates has decrease almost 2gb of memory use of JRUN. Now i am facing new error which i was facing earlier. I am editing my question with screen shot.

Comment: How did you arrive at "The minimum heap size is 1024 and max heap size is 2048." ithere is nothing specific in vm arguments, you should use -Xms znd -Xmx argument values to specify that.

Comment: #Fairoz, There is separate setting of this in coldfusion 9.

Comment: Please undo your edit and submit a new question with the new problem.

Comment: #Dan. I already submit a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698592/a-timeout-occur-while-attempting-to-local-fusebox