# A timeout occur while attempting to local fusebox

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, fusebox

I have a fusebox application setup on coldfusion 9 and it is in production mode. When application got started, it is giving me following error.

```
A timeout occur while attempting to local fusebox.
```

[image]

I have increased the timeout but that not help. Also tried other solution but nothing help.

There is one more thing. When i increased the JVM heap size from 1-2 gb to 2-3 gb. Then after restart of coldfusion service, Error remain for 1-2 hour and then site start working.

It also stop working after running for more than half day correctly. Then i get 504 gateway error and i have to restart the service again.

Can any one guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: It should you had a lock set on a previous crash. Try restarting the CF service and capture the original error

Comment: #James. I have restarted the CF service even server. But nothing happen. What do you mean by lock set?

Comment: Fusebox was created for older versions of ColdFusion. In older versions it was often important to use `<cflock>` to make a variables unchangeable for certain periods of time. As Seth Points out, if you are in production mode, this will happen a lot less. Confirm that you are in production mode

Comment: #james, it is working for today for one time when i change the heap size of jvm. But on server down, this error comes again.

Comment: Are you in prod or dev mode?

Comment: #James. It is in prod mode.

Comment: Try changing `exclusive` to `readOnly`. If that doesn't work, you have some kind of strange race condition which is beyond a quick diagnosis

Comment: #James, Thank for you reply. We have moved to a different setup with lucee setup and every thing got working properly now. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Which FB version are you running?  Is it set to production or development mode?  If set to development, try setting it to production mode.

Comment: @AbdulRauf - When you say "in production" do you mean the settings are configured for "production" mode? ie [From FAQ](http://fusebox.org/index.cfm/about/faq/fusebox-technical-faq/): *...In the fusebox.xml file there is a parameter for "mode". The mode can be set to various development modes or "production".*

Comment: #Leigh. Mode set to production. There is another thing. Yesterday i have increased the jvm heap size from 1-2 gb to 2-3 gb and now this error remain for 1 to 2 hour on site initialization OR on service restart and then site starting working.